# Difference between {\tt \{} and \verb+{+

Tags: verbatim, typewriter

Why is `{\tt \{}` typeset as an ordinary `{` and not the same as for instance `\verb+{+`?

To illustrate:

```
{\tt With tt:~ \{}

\verb+With verb: {+
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your document.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\tt` anyway, but either `\texttt{..}` or `\ttfamily`. The short font macros like `\tt` are only still present for backwards compatibility to LaTeX2.0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and it will be the same. Without the `T1` fontencoding the `\{` is taken from the `OMS` symbol font.

Comment: Well, `\{` is taken from the `OMS` symbol font (`cmsy10`) by default.

Comment: right, that was what I wanted to say ...